# Batch code to verify file existence in specific path/location?

Tags: batch-file, directory, location

I need guidance to write a batch code to verify that a file is in a specific directory.

What I want to do is something like:

If `find.txt` in `%SystemDrive%\Program Files\ABC\` then move to the next step without displaying any message.

Else display message `File not found` and close window automatically after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it in a rather roundabout way.

```
@echo off
IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\ABC\Find.txt" GOTO :NextCommand
@echo File not found
:NextCommand
```

So if the command is successful, it will go to the next label, and if not, it will print "File not found". You can add a pause/ exit after the @echo if you need to program to stop there if the file isn't found. Stephan's method works well too.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 when I attempt to edit. I meant Dileep and not Stephan.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest one. Hope it helps

```
Echo off
IF EXIST "%SystemDrive%\Program Files\ABC\find.txt" (
    ECHO found
) ELSE (
    ECHO file not found
)
timeout 5
```